# explode database values then echo by selected to a <select multiple> tag

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a example database where the fields are ID and UNIT, UNIT FIELD was in array records came from `<select multile>` tag.. Here is the Database ex..

```
 id| unit
 1 | A,B
 2 | C,D
 3 | E,F
```

What I would like to happen is to `EXPLODE` the values of `UNIT FIELD` using `EXPLODE(',',$result)`.. but how I will explode it, then get the `$result[0] or $result[1]` by each...  then I will echo it in `<select multiple>` tag again with `if(){echo selected='selected'}`.. Here it is what i would like to happen...

Example I `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1'`

```
<select multiple name="unit[]">
  <option <?php if($unit == 'A')echo selected='selected'?> > A: Unit </option>
  <option <?php if($unit == 'B')echo selected='selected'?> > B: Unit</option>
</select>
```

Thank You Guys Sorry for my English

Comment: you want to match all the unit field value in one <option> or the quantity of unit field would be equal to <option>???

Comment: e.g. `if (in_array('1', $result, true)) { ... }`

Comment: hi sir what would like to is explode the comma in A,B then echo`A` from one `option selected` then the `B` to other `option selected`. See my editing question sir tnxs

Answer (score 0):

**Below example is untested**.

Assuming you a are using `mysqli`:

```
$db = mysqli_connect([YOUR CONNECTION SETTINGS...]);
$sQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='1'";
$rResult = $db->query($sQuery);

$aResult = array();
while($aRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rResult)){
    aResult [] = $aRow;
}

// explode each row and store in a new array
 $aResultArrays = array();
 foreach ($aResult as $row){           
     $aResultArrays[$row['id']] = explode(',',$row['unit']);
 }
```

You should get array with keys representing `id` field with value `unit` array:

```
array(
[1] => array('A','B'),
[2] => array('C','D')
...
);
```

Comment: Tnxs for the reply sir, Sorry I typo error what I'd like to do is `explode comma in the UNIT field` using example `$result = explode(',' , $unit)` then get the $result[0] or $result[1] then echo by 'selected' to the `<select tag>`
ex.
`<select multiple name="unit[]">
  <option <?php if($unit == 'A')echo selected='selected'?> > A: Unit </option>
  <option <?php if($unit == 'B')echo selected='selected'?> > B: Unit</option>
</select>`